# Ordenar assosiativo e com valor

Tags: php, array

Gente eu tenho um array associativo e gostaria de ordenar por único indice com a somatória dos valores. Por exemplo.

```
$product = ['Arroz branco' => 36,'Arroz parborizado' => 10, 'Arroz Integral' => 1, 'Açúcar' => 547, 'Açúcar refinado' => 10' , 'Feijao de corda' => 10, 'Feijão preto' => 15, 'FERMENTO' => 854];
```

O retorno deverá ser:

```
$product = ['Arroz' => 47, 'Acucar' => 557, 'Feijao' => 25, 'Fermento' => 854 ];
```

Fico grato por qualquer ajuda.

Comment: E quais são as regras para se definir que são os mesmos índices? Sempre a primeira palavra? E se uma estiver maiúscula e outra minúscula?

Comment: Só a primeira palavra. Já consigo tratar tudo que é maiúsculas e minusculas colocar todas somente com a primeira letra Maiúscula.

Comment: E por que "Açúcar" virou "Acucar"?

Comment: Retiro acentuação e cedilha.

Comment: Certo, já tentou alguma coisa? Tem ideia de como pode ser feito?

Comment: Ja tentei de tudo, mas sempre perco informações quando eu formato as índices.

Comment: @JuniorOliveira veja minha resposta. Eu sei que ficou feio o código,mas fiz com amor pra você. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

Use o método `strpos` para compara se é parecido.

## Solução

```php
<?php
    $product = ['Arroz branco' => 36,'Arroz parborizado' => 10, 'Arroz Integral' => 1, 'Açúcar' => 547, 'Açúcar refinado' => 10 , 'Feijão de corda' => 10, 'Feijão preto' => 15, 'Fermento' => 854];
    $produto = ["Arroz" => 0,"Açúcar" => 0,"Feijão" => 0,"Fermento" => 0];
    foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key,"Arroz") !== false) {
            $produto["Arroz"] += $value;
        }
        if (strpos($key,"Açúcar") !== false) {
            $produto["Açúcar"] += $value;
        }
        if (strpos($key,"Feijão") !== false) {
            $produto["Feijão"] += $value;
        }
        if (strpos($key,"Fermento") !== false) {
            $produto["Fermento"] += $value;
        }
    }
    echo $produto["Arroz"];
    // 47
    echo $produto["Açúcar"];
    // 557
    echo $produto["Feijão"];
    // 25
    echo $produto["Fermento"];
    // 854
?>
```

## Fonte

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Faz sentido sim. usei strpos mas de forma diferente, possa ser que seu método der o resultado esperado. Não consigo da um 1 na sua resposta por que iniciei agora